# I need to format my computer with Windows 10 Insider Preview

Tags: windows-10

I have a Windows 10 Insider Preview installation from befora Windows 10 final was released (yes, it survived that long). Now I need to make a maintainance format on my computer.

I still have the CD-Key I got from Microsoft when I volunteered to try this beta version and the DVD I burnt the ISO Microsoft sent me.

If I install this version of Windows 10 and insert this CD-Key, will it work? Is there a way to avoid the need to download again all of the released upgrades and updates afterwards?

EDIT:

Will doing the instructions from [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/124286/how-to-uninstall-your-windows-product-key-before-you-sell-your-pc/) and then installing my CD-Key on a final version of Windows 10 installation work?

Comment: Just download the current Insider Preview build .ISO and install it The procedures you link to are not required since it is the same machine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all the Insider keys were deprecated in July, you'd probably need a 'real' Win 10 key or a valid Win 7 or 8

Comment: @Tetsujin - You are half right.  If you have a system or ever activated a system with a key, then it can still be used, its just new activation won't happen.  Since the machine is already activated, and Windows 10 activation is a digital entitlement, the user will not run into a problem.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't know about that, I'm still getting system updates as they roll out and never got any kind of warning from Windows neither by email about such thing.

Comment: @Ramhound So do you think that if I follow the steps to uninstall the product key from my current installation, format it, install the final Windows 10 version and activate the same product key on that, it won't work?

Comment: @Ramhound - ah, I see. I had one machine I tried to get on the Insider during July & got stuck at that point; wasn't sure about once you'd got it established. I ended up dropping 2 machines back to win 7 then upgrading after the release. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Microsoft stop new activation in July in the weeks leading to July 29th 2015.  They basically stopped new machine activations shortly before the release of the Insider Preview 10240 .ISO

Comment: @Ramhound I noticed now you edited your first comment. I'll try it then. What if I plan on switching my computer's hard drive? I want to install a solid state drive on it and install Windows 10 on this drive instead.

Comment: @BrunoFinger - Your system drive plays absolutely no part in the digital entitlement.  I suggest using the last Insider Preview .ISO that was released, this way you are not trying to install the retail product, with an Insider Preview key.  Of course even that might not work, if that is the case, you don't have an option except to update from the .ISO you already have.

Comment: @Ramhound great I'll try it and post it here if it worked later. Thanks.